# Setting a data format common to all analysis in obiee 12c

Tags: obiee, oracle-bi

Is there any common configuration in OBIEE 12c , which allows to define decimal places applicable to all analysis?

For example,presently, if you want to set the decimal places for currency column, you need to take the data format of that column and change there. My requirement is to set the decimal places of currency type to a digit, which is applicable for all analysis in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You first of all have the locale defaults per language. Then you always have the ability to format a column the way you want and then say "Save as..." and then "default for "Table"."Column"" which will format all.occurrences of this column the same way or "default for data type" which will apply it to all date columns for example.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I updated the 'digits' attribute to 4 in 'bi/bifoundation/web/display/currencies.xml' . After that , the column properties is showing 4 as the default decimal place, it works fine. But in some places I am overriding the number column as currency. Those places will not update , if I change the digits in currencies.xml .  Is there any solution for this?

Comment: If you have manually set values, those values will always win over either XML changes or "Save as default". You need to un-set those manual changes yourself.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. My issues is the column type by default is number and I need to change it to currency via properties , to display currency symbol and all. Is there any way to set a column type as currency from RPD?

Comment: No. Currency is front-end only.